# Laravel - How to prepare for deprecation of Basic authentication in Exchange Online?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, web-deployment

After reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online) article, it looks like basic SMTP auth will be disabled for emails. How will this effect laravel applications that use SMTP with a username/password to authenticate? How can we prepare for this, and change our email authentication methods? I have a few projects that use SMTP with outlook emails, and I am worried they will break once this change takes place.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all `SMTP` never be removed. Helper libraries got changed with time. Second thing, can you please paste link of article that you have read?

Comment: @khawarAli Sorry, I forgot to link it when I first posted the question. Here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Comment: Are you using an Exchange driver for your Laravel application? If so, which one?

Comment: @waterloomatt Unsure. Using the SMTP mail driver, with the host being an office365 one, authenticating with username+pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no change needed, authentication wasn't deprecated for SMTP mail drivers.